# jQuery finish slide before next mouseover

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have a list of span tags that fire a mouseover event which updates the src attribute and slides the next image in. The problem I am having is that if a user rolls over a number of the controls in quick succession then the animation becomes very jumpy and looks bad. Below is my current code:

```
$("#list .client").mouseover(function(){
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr('rel');
    var image1 = $("#clientImage1");
    var image2 = $("#clientImage2");

    if(image1.is(":visible")){
        image2.attr('src', imgSrc); 
        image2.stop(true, true).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 400);  
        image1.stop(true, true).hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 400);
        //image1.hide();
    }
    else{
        image1.attr('src', imgSrc);
        image1.stop(true, true).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 400);
        image2.stop(true, true).hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 400);
    }
    //console.log("Img Source: " + imgSrc);
});
```

What I would like to do is add a time delay if there is currently an animation still in progress. I do not want to queue functions, just perform the last one called on the last mouseover. I assume it has something to do with SetTimeout but I am a little confused as to how to acheive this.

Any ideas?

### Thanks!

Edit:

Thanks so much for your help, finally got it to work with hoverIntent! 
The working code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#clientImage2").hide();  
    $("#list .client").hoverIntent(config); 

});


var config = {    
     over: slideShow, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
     timeout: 600, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
     out: doNothing // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)    
};
function slideShow() {
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr('rel');
    var image1 = $("#clientImage1");
    var image2 = $("#clientImage2");

    if(image1.is(":visible")){
      image2.attr('src', imgSrc); 
      image2.stop(true, true).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 600);  
      image1.stop(true, true).hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 600);
      }
    else{
      image1.attr('src', imgSrc);
      image1.stop(true, true).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 600);
      image2.stop(true, true).hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 600);
      }
}

function doNothing(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do 2 things.

First, you oculd use the hoverIntent plugin which will ignore quick mouseovers, or you could unbind the mouseover action until the animation is complete.

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Edit:

Use unbind as such:

```
$("#list .client").mouseover(function(){
   $("#list .client").unbind('mouseover');
}
```

Make the function that does all of this a named function instead of anonymous. Then when the animation of the image showing completes. rebind the mouseover function the same way you bind it in the first place

```
function slideShow() { 
$("#list .client").unbind('mouseover');
 var imgSrc = $(this).attr('rel');
var image1 = $("#clientImage1");
var image2 = $("#clientImage2");

  if(image1.is(":visible")){
      image2.attr('src', imgSrc); 
      image2.stop(true, true).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 400, function() {
         $("#list .client").mouseover(slideShow);
      });  
              image1.stop(true, true).hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 400);
              //image1.hide();
      }
      else{
          image1.attr('src', imgSrc);
          image1.stop(true, true).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 400);
          image2.stop(true, true).hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 400);
    }

    // binding
    $("#list .client").mouseover(slideShow);
```

Comment: I had a play around with HoverIntent but with no luck. Would you be able to give me an example of how to unbind and then rebind my using my code as an example? Sorry I am kind of new to jquery.

Comment: Check my edit.  Sorry if there is a little error, but that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

usually when you do animations you want to stop previous animations, so before you do an animation you can insert a .stop(true, true) before the animation (like `$("#myelement").stop(true,true).fadeIn()` for example). The first 'true' clears the animation queue for the element, the second 'true' stops the currently running animation.